# Dual Booting Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 12.0 alongside Windows 7. When I boot up and the select screen comes up the up/down selector buttons become inoperable and Ubuntu is automatically selected.

Answer (score 0):

The boot up screen is called GRUB. Boot Ubuntu and try the following from a Terminal.

1. Select the Linux kernels you want to be displayed by leaving only the kernel files in the `/boot` folder.

   `cd /boot`

   `sudo mkdir old_kernels`

   `sudo mv *undesired_kernel* old_kernels`   [e.g. `sudo mv 0-26 old_kernels`]
2. Modify the grub option editing

   `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
3. `sudo update-grub`

If you want to know more look [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html#mozTocId624480).

Comment: Thanks for your help, please walk me through this I am a novice.